# Rsyncable compression library

Tags: .net, compression, gzip, zlib

Could you recommend me any Windows (preferably .NET) library that allows to compress data that would be rsync compatible, i.e. behaving in a way that gzip --rsyncable does. I found some request changes for zlib, but it seems it have not been implemented.
I tried to used some parallel compression algorithms thinking that it would do compression independently on blocks, but with no luck (any change in original file makes the compressed one to be changed completely).

--> EDIT

I grabbed a DotNetZip library that exposes ZLib sync modes and use it with constant buffer of 4096 and Sync flush mode, but again even a small change in input file makes a output file to be completety different. What is that I could do wrong?

```cs
using (var inputStream = new FileStream("file.in", FileMode.Open))
using (var outputStream = new FileStream("file.out", FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(outputStream, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int n;
        while ((n = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            compressor.FlushMode = FlushType.Sync;
            compressor.Write(buffer, 0, n);
            compressor.Flush();
            // actually, Flush() is not needed, DeflateStream automatically flushes on every write.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do the syncs cannot be simply periodic. It must depend on the input data. You need to read the link to the source code that I provided.

Comment: @gregi Did you manage to achive rsyncable defalte compression in .NET, can you share the code?

Comment: @Stritof I did and make a nuget library out of it: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastRsyncNet.Compression/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/) for this, which already provides all you need. It's simply a matter of inserting `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` flushes often enough, but not too often, triggered by patterns in the uncompressed data.

You can look at the example in [pigz's implementation](https://github.com/madler/pigz/blob/master/pigz.c#L430), using a very simple hash of the input data, looking for a 12-bit pattern. You could use 13 bits instead, for less of a compression impact. See the comments.